# MySQL Opposite of Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, logical-operators

I know in other languages you can use something (usually a `!`) to denote the opposite of whatever follows. Is there a way to do something like this in MySQL?

For example, I have this query to select everything that isn't null or blank:

```
select * from `invoices` where `Notes`>'';
```

But is there a way way to do the opposite? Because currently I only know that you can rewrite the query such as this

```
select * from `invoices` where ifnull(`Notes`,'')='';
```

But this removes the opportunity for indexes on the `Notes` column or this way

```
select * from `invoices` where (`Notes` is null or `Notes`='');
```

But that one is a lot longer than something like

```
select * from `invoices` where !`Notes`>'';
```

which would be ideal.

Comment: Why not makes notes 'not nullable', with a default value of ''?

Comment: `where not notes >''`; though I'm not certain if that would use an index.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a `not` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE NOT (`Notes`>'');
-- Here -----------------------^
```

Comment: Hmm... I seem to be missing something. When I do this, I don't get any results, does this not work the way I'm thinking with `null` fields?

Comment: This solution appears to be acting the same way as `select * from \`invoices\` where \`Notes\`<='';` which doesn't work with my `null` columns

Comment: So is there an actual solution that works with `NULL` values, or no?